# function variable not being passed to setState correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Granted, I have been away from React for a while, but this should be more in the category of plain JS.

I have the following setState function:

```
// click event on parent for performance reasons
``Component:``
const [active, setActive] = useState({ "": false });
return (
  <div onClick={handleClick}>
     <List>{items}</List>
  </div>
)
```

And the click event:

```
const handleClick = event => {
    const item = event.target;
    const li = item.classList;
    const attr = item.attributes.listid.value;

    li.toggle("selected");
    // Why is attr not getting used correctly?
    setActive({ attr: !active });
  };
```

The variable `attr` is not being used in the setState event. "Attr is assigned a value but never used". When I `console.log(useState)` after the click function I see {attr: false} (before it's `null: false`).

Why is the variable not being used, and how do I use it correctly?

Comment: why you use `""` as key ? why not a proper name ? you want to have key as per the value or attr variable ? or want to change key's value as per attr ?

Answer (score 1):

> before it's `null: false`

The initial value of `active` is `{ "": false }` as indicated in your `useState`.

> Why is the variable not being used, and how do I use it correctly?

The code isn't using `active` state.

To use it when interacting with the list items, you can have something like:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState({});

const handleClick = event => {
  // ... get item ...
  const attr = item.attributes.listid.value;

  setActive({ [attr]: !active[attr] });
};

const renderList = (items) => {
  return (
    <List>
      {items.map((item) => <Item active={active[item.attr]} />)}
    </List>
  );
};

return (
  <div onClick={handleClick}>
    {renderList(items)}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Things i will change is first use a proper name for key instead of `""`

```
const [active, setActive] = useState({ active: false });
```

If you intended to just toggle boolean valule we don't need `attr` at all

```
setActive({ active: !active });
```

---

> Why attr "Attr is assigned a value but never used" ?

```
setActive({ attr: !active });
```

This line is adding a property named `attr` ( just plain string ) but not using the `attr` variable, so you're getting `"Attr is assigned a value but never used"`

If you intended to use `attr` variable's value as key's name you need to use `computed property accessor []`

```
 setActive({ [attr]: !active });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate the item list in its own component and then render it in your List component like this:

```
const ListItem = ({item}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleClick =() => {
    active ? setActive(false) : setActive(true);
  };

  return (
    <li className={active ? 'selected' : ''}>{item}</li>
  )
}
```

```
// click event on parent for performance reasons
``Component:``
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
return (
  <div onClick={handleClick}>
     <List>{items.map((item) => (<ListItem item={item} />))}</List>
  </div>
)
```

and active itself will toggle to true or false.